What does AddMovementInput function actually do?
I'm currently trying to understand what my options are for character movement, however every source so far has used the addmovementinput function that is part of the character base class.
It works closely to what I need so I would like to write something similar but I cant without understanding what the function is actually doing.
In other words I want to understand how the addmovementinput function is able to move a character with precise velocity and direction while also detecting collisions

See the docs. If you still need more clarification, then I’ll write an answer.
